# Reading data from files in python with intelligent format

Tags: python, numpy

I have this data table:

[image]

Ciudad means City, Fase means Phase and Tarea mins Task

The data table is saved into a file with this format:

```
Giron 20 15,18 40 50 60,77 37 45
Floridablanca 17 13,17 35 43 55,67 39 46
Bogota 15 12,17 35 43 55,67 39 46
Cali 14 12,10 30 40 32,59 67 33
```

The numbers means millions (20 Million, 18 million, etc.)

**Each city is a line. Phases are delimited by "," and tasks are delimited by space**

I need to read this file from python and be able to work with the tasks and phases of every single city, calculate what is the more expensive tasks in a city, the most expensive phase, etc.

The problem is that I dont really know how to read and save the data in order to start to calculate what I need to calculate

I have been trying with 1d-arrays and 2d-arrays with Numpy (loadtxt, genfromtxt), but the data output is not so clear and I can't figure out how to work with it

Comment: @AlexHall the `1` is a link to an image.

Comment: How is your data table saved? It would probably be easier to use [tag:pandas] to parse the file then numpy.

Comment: Your question is not clear. In what format(s) do you need to read data from, and in what formats do you need to write them?

Comment: My data table is saved in a txt with the format below the image. I need to read the data with that format and work whit it into my script. But I need to separate by city and work with every single city. Sorry if you dont understand me well. My english is not so good

Comment: With the table image and file sample the question is fairly clear.  The primary task is to load a list (or lists) of names and numbers.  Once read and parse, it is easy to arrange things into arrays.  Can there be spaces in the names?  It's the mix of commas and spaces as delimiters that gives stock readers like `loadtxt` problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
line = 'Santa Rosa de Cabal 20 15,18 40 50 60,77 37 45'
city, phase1, phase2, phase3 = re.match(
    '(.+) (\d+ \d+),(\d+ \d+ \d+ \d+),(\d+ \d+ \d+)', line).groups()

def tasks(phase_string):
    return [int(task) for task in phase_string.split()]

print(city)
for phase in phase1, phase2, phase3:
    print(tasks(phase))
```

Output:

```
Santa Rosa de Cabal
[20, 15]
[18, 40, 50, 60]
[77, 37, 45]
```

The main thing here is regular expressions. Read about them.

Comment: `line = 'Santa Rosa de Cabal 20 15,18 40 50 60,77 37 45` — [Santa Rosa de Cabal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Rosa_de_Cabal) is a town and municipality in the Risaralda Department, of west central Colombia...

Comment: I agree, regular expression is the most powerful way of splitting these lines, especially if there are spaces in the names.

Comment: It worked perfect!. How Would you find what is the most expensive phase of a city?

Comment: Austin's answer has the general idea. Try combining that with this answer. If you get stuck post a new question showing your efforts and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple parsing task, but you have to approach it in stages. First parse some, then for each bit parse a little more, etc.

Try this:

```
#!python3
import io

File = """Giron 20 15,18 40 50 60,77 37 45
Floridablanca 17 13,17 35 43 55,67 39 46
Bogota 15 12,17 35 43 55,67 39 46
Cali 14 12,10 30 40 32,59 67 33
"""

Ciudades = {}

with io.StringIO(File) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip():
            ciudad,costs = line.split(' ', 1)
            Ciudades[ciudad] = fases = {}
            for fase,tareacosts in enumerate(costs.split(',')):
                fn = "Fase {}".format(fase)
                fases[fn] = list(map(int, tareacosts.split(' ')))

print("Most expensive tarea in Bogota Fase 2 is:",
        max(Ciudades['Bogota']['Fase 2']))
```

Comment: I had a similar approach but it was pointed out that the city name might have a space.